# Encoding of PDF dictionaries

Tags: pdf, encoding

I need to know the encoding of the values of PDF dictionaries (not the text displayed to the user but the "code behind").
I plan not to use any library for that.
Where can I find it?

Comment: Do the answers answer all your questions? Or are there any open issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the encoding of the values of PDF dictionaries

Values of PDF dictionaries are PDF objects.

You should take a look at the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), in particular chapter 7 *Syntax*, to find out about PDF objects. You will find:

> The tokens that delimit objects and that describe the structure of a PDF file shall use the ASCII character
>   set. In addition all the reserved words and the names used as keys in PDF standard dictionaries and
>   certain types of arrays shall be defined using the ASCII character set.

Thus, most of the time you have to deal with ASCII values.

The situation is tricky with strings, though, because there are several types of strings which use the same string syntax options, so you have to interpret their contents according to their context.

> Table 35 – String Object Types
>
> *Type* Description
>
> *text string* Shall be used for human-readable text, such as text
>   annotations, bookmark names, article names, and
>   document information. These strings shall be encoded
>   using either PDFDocEncoding or UTF-16BE with a
>   leading byte-order marker.
>   This type is described in 7.9.2.2, "Text String Type."
>
> *PDFDocEncoded string* Shall be used for characters and glyphs that are
>   represented in a single byte, using PDFDocEncoding.
>   This type is described in 7.9.2.3, "PDFDocEncoded String
>   Type."
>
> *ASCII string* Shall be used for characters that are represented in a
>   single byte using ASCII encoding.
>
> *byte string* Shall be used for binary data represented as a series of
>   bytes, where each byte can be any value representable in
>   8 bits. The string may represent characters but the
>   encoding is not known. The bytes of the string need not
>   represent characters. This type shall be used for data
>   such as MD5 hash values, signature certificates, and Web
>   Capture identification values.
>   This type is described in 7.9.2.4, "Byte String Type."

If a string is the value e.g. of the **Author** metadata, it is a text string, so it is encoded using either PDFDocEncoding or UTF-16BE with a leading byte-order marker.

If on the other hand a string is the value e.g. of **Contents** in a signature dictionary, it is a byte string holding a binary object, any attempt to interpret it according to some *encoding* will fail.

The situation is even more tricky with streams.

First of all the stream content may be somehow processed, e.g. it may be compressed. To get to the actual stream contents, you first have to undo this processing.

The the content may either be binary, e.g. a font program, or text, e.g. JavaScript, or it may be a content stream, e.g. the page contents.

> A content stream is a PDF stream object whose data consists of a sequence of instructions describing the
>   graphical elements to be painted on a page. The instructions shall be represented in the form of PDF objects,
>   using the same object syntax as in the rest of the PDF document.

Thus, they are mostly ASCII values. The exception again are string arguments to text drawing instructions. Their encoding depends entirely on the font currently selected when the string is drawn, and fonts may use standard encodings, but they may also use completely chaotic, ad-hoc encodings.

**PS:** If you happen to try and analyze an encrypted PDF, you will find that *Encryption
applies to all strings and streams in the document's PDF file, with very few exceptions*. In particular encryption does not apply to dictionary and array structures, numbers and names. Thus, someone not aware of this might not recognize that the PDF is encrypted but instead assume that strings and streams are encoded in a very weird way.

Answer (score 2):

You find that in the PDF specification (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html). To elaborate a bit on the most important points in your question...

1) PDF dictionaries can contain a variety of value types (booleans, numbers, strings...). The encoding you are going to encounter depends on the type of value.

2) Mostly, the interesting and complex case is that where the type of object is a string.

3) For a string, read section 7.9.2 in the PDF specification. That explains what encodings can be used for such strings (PDFDocEncoding, Unicode encoding...) and how to recognise what encoding you have for a particular string.

Answer (score 1):

To complement @mkl's and @DavidvanDriessche's excellent answers...

Here are three OpenSource command line tools which can help you to transform any PDF into different forms which expand/uncompress/decode object streams *(Note, there is not one single, "the-one-and-only-correct" way to do this -- so the outputs of each of the tools will be different)*:

1. **[`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)**
2. **[`mutool`](http://mupdf.com/)**
3. **[`qpdf`](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf)**

Each of these should be available via your favorite operating systems package manager.

**`pdftk`example usage:**

```
pdftk in.pdf cat output out1.pdf uncompress
```

**`mutool` example usage:**

```
mutool clean -d in.pdf out2.pdf
```

**`qpdf` example usage (my favorite tool for this purpose):**

```
qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable in.pdf out3.pdf
```

You should try each of these, compare their outputs for different input PDFs and then decide which one is your favorite (but never forget to remember the other tools when you encounter a case where your favorite shows unexpected results).